# Gmail rejects messages from new exim4 setup

Tags: ipv6, spam, exim, gmail

I have problem with delivering mails to GMail from a new server setup with configured exim4.

Messages sometime passed to gmail spam folder. But sometimes it rejects immediatelly. I have attached a success of incoming message to gmail.

Here is message source: http://dpaste.com/0KT384Z

I have tried disable ipv6 in exim4 without socuces. GMail already have in logs my pubic IPv6.

BUT. I have a right PTR and SPF records which shows in source as PASS.

I have no any ideas where I can get a help. I have used a google support page for get a support from google. but no any answers got in 10 days...

I dont know what I can todo. Can anyone helps me?

**UPDATED**: 
Source of returned mail http://dpaste.com/3STSAMW.txt , here also is a **reason** why it's returned. The DMARC, SPF, and PTRs of my server IP is normal and displayed in delivered emails as PASS. Here is a test result from mail-tester.com: https://www.mail-tester.com/test-uyg3k

**PROBLEM SOLVED**
The real problem was at Hetzner IPs, a lot of them are blacklisted, if you remove it with manual request to blacklist admin. GMail does not remove, and consider that IPs as unwanted. After got a really clean IP which never was in blacklists all seems fine.

Comment: Which MUA I need to use. I have no ideas. Just a custom one?

Comment: Changed MUA to just "hosted.pw", now emails just in SPAM folder of gmail. The text message which goes to SPAM I already put in question post. This message appears in spam: http://dpaste.com/00E4WYG.txt

Answer (score 0):

Haha, I think any message with the subject Привет is a bit suspicious!

But seriously, here is the relevant bit of the SMTP failure:

```
    550-5.7.1 [2a01:4f8:1c1c:b36a::3      12] Our system has detected that this
    550-5.7.1 message is likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent
    550-5.7.1 to Gmail, this message has been blocked. Please visit
    550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=UnsolicitedMessageError
    550 5.7.1  for more information. o18si5225169wrq.380 - gsmtp
```

If you [visit that link](https://support.google.com/mail/?p=UnsolicitedMessageError), it will explain that you can use Gmail Postmaster Tools to register your domain and get more information about why messages are rejected or marked as spam.

> [Gmail Postmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6227174) provides senders with metrics on parameters such as reputation, spam rate, feedback loop, etc. It can help you check compliance to the Gmail bulk sender guidelines, as well as identify issues that can cause trouble with the spam filter.

Register at [postmaster.google.com](https://postmaster.google.com/), verify your domain, and then check the Delivery Errors Dashboard to find detailed information about why each message is rejected.

Comment: I already registered at GMail Postmaster tools, but there are always shows the message "Empty data nothing to show" if I check a domain in postmaster tools. Also, changing the subject got nothing, the mail is in spam folder again: http://dpaste.com/0QQFN51.txt

Comment: You didn't see a new entry in the postmaster tools after you sent the message?

Comment: Yes. I dont see anything, only a message about "No data" and a link to postmaster requirements, in requirements there are a text about a thousands and hundreds mail messages which must be sent from my server. But my users does not send this lot of messages to gmail, it's a small server for few companies which is not sending a lot of emails, just have a working correspondence with clients. Really I can write a script which sends a lot of mails to random gmail recipients, but it looks like something crazy.

Comment: echo "Subject: Hello my friend, i am glad to hear you." | /usr/sbin/exim4 -v ayanami.dev@gmail.com

goes to spam :\

Comment: Google really doesn't like you? Are you clicking "Not Spam"?

Comment: If I click "Not a spam" - mails from this user goes to Inbox directory. But from other user - Spam folder...
Maybe google does not like hetzner IPs

Comment: Seems the problem solved, after getting five unclean IPs in hetzner cloud, got a clean one. which not listed in any DNSBL lists. The mails goes to inbox. After this I all tested on unclean IP. I just do a request of removing IP from a blacklist, they remove it. But google does not. Anyway, many thanx for helping.

Comment: @MichaelHampton WTF, what's so suspicious about "Привет"?  -1 for spreading the bigotry!

Comment: @cnst What in the hell are you talking about? Bigotry?